# codeigniter db->delete() returns true always?

Tags: php, ajax, json, codeigniter

i have displayed table with record and "Delete" image. on delete image click i am deleting the record using ajax. supose there are three records with id 40,41,42
if i delete record with ID = 40, responce returns "1" and record gets deleted,
next time if i again click on delete image it again returns "1".

codeigniters db->delete() method returns "1" always ?
do i need to check manually if record exists and then proceed to delete ?
below is my code iin ajax.php

```
$res = $this->db->delete(tbl_user_groups, array('owner_id' => $admin,'user_group_id'=>$gid)); 

if($res) echo json_encode (array("success"=>"true"));
else     echo json_encode (array("success"=>"false"));
```

Comment: Relevant post with additional advice/explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64921680/2943403

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The **db->delete()** returns `TRUE`, if delete operation is successful. It would only return `FALSE` if it COULDN’T delete the row. I think you should be checking something like:

```
$this->db->affected_rows();
```

which returns number and not a Boolean, which you can check with your If conditions.

Answer (score 7):

when we delete from db in codeigniter 2.2.0
using `$this->db->delete()` we can operate with two flags:
1. `$this->db->_error_message()`
and
2. `$this->db->affected_rows()`

So after db query we get 1 and 2 like:

DELETED: '', 1

NOT DELETED: '', 0 // row with id not found, but sql completed ok

> SQL ERROR: string, -1

My choice is the following check:

```
$this->db->delete($this->table,array('id'=>$id));
if ($this->db->_error_message()) {
    $result = 'Error! ['.$this->db->_error_message().']';
} else if (!$this->db->affected_rows()) {
    $result = 'Error! ID ['.$id.'] not found';
} else {
    $result = 'Success';
}
```

Comment: as of CI 3.0 this outputs: `Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::error_message()` - seems like the best method is to use affected_rows()

Comment: @taber it has changed to `$this->db->error()` in CI 3.0 which returns an array containing `code` and `message`. Use `$this->db->error()['message']` to fetch the error message.