# How can I detect a create, update, delete query is successful in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I am currently writing a controller method like this:

```
public function delete($user_id) {
    if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD')=='POST') {
        $result = $this->Crm_user_model->update($user_id,
                                                array('deleted'=>true));
        if($result) {
            add_flash_message('info', 'deleted');
        } else {
            add_flash_message('alert', 'can not delete');
        }
        //redirect('user/view');
    }
}
```

But all result return nothing, even the database(mssql) is changed.
How can I know that the update query is success or not?

Comment: It would help if you post the models `update()` function. Whether `$result` is true or false will depend on what that function returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `crm_user_model->update()`, return `true` or `false` depending on the output of CodeIgniter's `update()` function:

```
if ($this->db->update('mytable', $mydata)) {
    // Do some stuff
    return true;
} else {
    // Do some stuff
    return false;
}
```

Or if you don't need to do anything else in your model, just do this:

`return $this->db->update('mytable', $mydata);`

Answer (score 1):

I have a concern and some advice.

1. **Controller**: You should not be passing the `$user_id` value to your `delete` controller via the url.  (such as `site/ci/delete/99`)  Whenever you are "writing" data to the database/server you should only be using `$_POST` to transfer the data to the server-side.

   ```
   public function softDeleteUser(): void
   {
       $userId = $this->input->post('user_id');
       if (!$userId) {
           add_flash_message('alert', 'Required data not supplied');
       } elseif (!$this->Crm_user_model->update($userId, ['deleted' => true])) {
           add_flash_message('alert', 'Failed to soft delete user');
       } else {
           add_flash_message('info', 'Soft deleted user');
       }
   }
   ```

   If no `user_id` is POST'ed, then `$userId` will be declared as `null`.

   If your database schema cannot store a boolean value (`true`), then it is common to use `1` and `0` as boolean equivalents.

   I prefer to write all negative/erroring/non-successful outcomes before successful ones when constructing condition blocks.

   A user authentication/authorization check before allowing the soft deletion of a user would be advisable so that only privileged users have permission to take this action.
2. **Model**: Your querying should be done solely in the model.  Because it is possible that a query might not have syntax errors, but also makes no change to the database, you must check the process at two points.

   Consider the situations like:

   1. the `$userId` that is passed to the controller does not exist in the database or
   2. the row containing the `$userId` is already "soft deleted".

   In both of these cases, the query will not fail, but there will be no affected rows.  These are relevant occurrences for your script to differentiate from *actual* changing updates.

   ```
   public function update(int $userId, array $newData): int
   {
       // ensure that no one can ever modify the user_id column value
       unset($newData['user_id']);

       if ($this->db->update('user_tablename', $newData, ['user_id' => $userId])) {
           $affectedRows = $this->db->affected_rows();
           if ($affectedRows) {
               // potentially log successful change if your system keeps track of change history
               // $this->Log->userChange($userId, $newData);
           }
           return $affectedRows;
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   If there is a syntax error, it will be in your error logs.

Comment: I'm trying to learn a bit of CodeIgniter and I found your helpful answer here. Thanks!