# How to catch database error in codeigniter when there is an error in deleting?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I want to customize or handle the query error delete in codeigniter but the problem is it doesn't work. 
How do I handle it using try catch or if else statements?

Controller:

```
public function delete($id){
    $this->load->model('m_customer_info');
    $delete=$this->m_customer_info->delete_data($id);

    $this->get_all_customers(); 
}
```

Model:

```
public function delete_data($id){
    $delete="delete from member where idno='$id'";

    try{
        $this->db->query($delete);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Cannot delete because it is a club officer')</script>";
    }

    /*if($delete==true){
        $this->db->query($delete);
    }
    else
        echo "<script>alert('Cannot delete because it is a club officer')</script>";
    */      
}
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093334/codeigniter-db-delete-returns-true-always) q/a.

Answer (score 1):

**In Model**

```
public function delete_data($id){

    $this->db->where('idno', $id);
    if (!$this->db->delete('member')) {
        # Delete Failed
        return false;
    }  
    else{
        # delete Sucess
        return true;
    }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $this->load->model('m_customer_info');
    $delete = $this->m_customer_info->delete_data($id);
    if ($delete == false) {
        echo "Delete Failed";
    }
    else{
        $this->get_all_customers(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: still displays like this: [Please take a look](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bfg900jdq4czo41/catch_error.PNG?dl=0)

Comment: Chk the error u deleting the row that have foriegn key.. @help-me

Comment: @HelpMe Yes you cant do tht. cz there is foreign key. So create another column call is_deletd. defult is 0. if deletd is updated to 1

Comment: The error there displays because of the foreign key and that's ok for me. I just want to change or  replace the error message.

Comment: Ahh no you cant do it cz its in CI. and make your environmnt to production and test

Comment: Is there any other option?

Comment: @HelpMe no. you have to do like that. Use column and then can customize message. But Not In CI messages

Comment: Why is it impossible?

Comment: @HelpMe thats not customizeable message. Cz its error of your code. Got it?