# num_rows on delete query codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to find a way to validate that my Delete query was successful. How can I get num_rows or affected_rows from the following structure:

```
public function fire_db($currentUserID, $id_staff){
        $this->db->where('id_player', $currentUserID);
        $this->db->where('id_hired_staff', $id_staff);
        $this->db->limit(1); 
        $this->db->delete('game_hired_staff'); 
        if ($this->db->num_rows() == 1) {
            return true; 
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Using codeigniter 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to test result of delete query use

```
$this->db->affected_rows();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
public function fire_db($currentUserID, $id_staff){
    $this->db->where('id_player', $currentUserID);
    $this->db->where('id_hired_staff', $id_staff);
    $this->db->limit(1); 

    if (!$this->db->delete('game_hired_staff')) {
        return false;
    }
    else
        print_r($this->db->affected_rows());            
    }
```

> Possible duplicate of [codeigniter db->delete() returns true always?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9093466/4595675)